# sorting two fields.I want to sort the file primarily by field 1, and secondarily by field 2 (the second field need to be sorted lexicographically)

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, unix

I have this content of a file:

```
0 elza 0 0
0 Rita 0 0
0 genia 0 0
0 ben 0 0
0 Moshe 0 0
1 Ben 0 1
2 Roi 1 1
1 Noam 0 1
1 beni 1 0
0 ben 0 0
1 roi 0 1
2 Roi 1 1
0 ben 0 0
```

the purpose is to sort the file primarily by field 1(the bigger number is first etc), and secondarily by field 2 (the second field need to be sorted lexicographically). Then cut the first field.

I tried to use this line command to achieve it:

```
sort | uniq | sort -k 1,1n -r -k 2,2 | cut -c3-
```

But i get this :
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S90LB.png)

The correct order is this(but i can't get to this with my command line):

```
Roi 1 1
Ben 0 1
Noam 0 1
beni 1 0
roi 0 1
Moshe 0 0
Rita 0 0
ben 0 0
elza 0 0
genia 0 0
```

Comment: I honestly cannot see what pattern you have there.  The first field (names) are in no particular order, nor is the second field, nor the third.

Comment: The first field is numbers, the second fiels is names.

Comment: Please add sample input for that sample output to your question.

Comment: That is not what you have where you say, "I need to get this order."

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve. Please provide short example data and the result of the sorting. Just sorting, without any further processing.

Comment: I add a sample input at the end, where i wrote "without the command line i wrote i get this order:".  Jack the order is need to be first according to the sum between the two numbers(the input sample has it has the first field) and the secondarily by lexicographically order of the names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sort capital letters before lowercase letters:

```
LC_COLLATE=C sort -u -k1,1nr -k2,2 file | cut -d " " -f 2-
```

Output:

```
Roi 1 1
Ben 0 1
Noam 0 1
beni 1 0
roi 0 1
Moshe 0 0
Rita 0 0
ben 0 0
elza 0 0
genia 0 0
```

Comment: I'm writing:   | sort -u -k1,1nr -k2,2 file | cut -d " " -f 2-   (I'm using a pipe line to do this commands. Maybe that the reason why it's not working?          I used what yo wrote ang got this :                                                      Roi 1 1  
Ben 0 1  
beni 1 0  
Noam 0 1  
roi 0 1  
ben 0 0  
elza 0 0  
genia 0 0  
Moshe 0 0  
Rita 0 0

Comment: Switch from file to stdin: `| LC_COLLATE=C sort -u -k1,1nr -k2,2 | cut -d " " -f 2-`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat file.txt
0 elza 0 0
0 Rita 0 0
0 genia 0 0
0 ben 0 0
0 Moshe 0 0
1 Ben 0 1
2 Roi 1 1
1 Noam 0 1
1 beni 1 0
0 ben 0 0
1 roi 0 1
2 Roi 1 1
0 ben 0 0

$ sort -u -k 1nr -k 2dr file.txt
2 Roi 1 1
1 roi 0 1
1 Noam 0 1
1 beni 1 0
1 Ben 0 1
0 Rita 0 0
0 Moshe 0 0
0 genia 0 0
0 elza 0 0
0 ben 0 0
```

Comment: Ah, did not understand that you wanted all Capitalized words, then all lowercase.  Was definitely not clear in the problem statement.